# How to get span text only from a table?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In this HTML I am trying to parse the text fields and the impact but impact is not text its an image

```
<td class="fxs_c_item fxs_c_time"><span>01:00</span></td>,
 <td class="fxs_c_item fxs_c_flag"><span class="fxs_flag fxs_us" title="United States"></span></td>,
 <td class="fxs_c_item fxs_c_currency"><span>USD</span></td>,
 <td class="fxs_c_item fxs_c_name"><span>New Year's Day</span><span> <span></span></span></td>,
 <td class="fxs_c_item fxs_c_impact"><span class="fxs_c_impact-icon fxs_c_impact-none"></span></td>,
 <td class="fxs_c_item fxs_c_type" colspan="4"><span class="fxs_c_label fxs_c_label_info">All Day</span></td>,
 <td class="fxs_c_item fxs_c_notify"></td>,
 <td class="fxs_c_item fxs_c_dashboard" data-gtmid="features-calendar-eventdetails-eventoptions-4d3300ad-c168-4a5f-a4ac-a60a338e63c4"><span><svg aria-hidden="true" class="fxs_icon svg-inline--fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-w-16" data-icon="ellipsis-h" data-prefix="fas" focusable="false" role="img" viewbox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M328 256c0 39.8-32.2 72-72 72s-72-32.2-72-72 32.2-72 72-72 72 32.2 72 72zm104-72c-39.8 0-72 32.2-72 72s32.2 72 72 72 72-32.2 72-72-32.2-72-72-72zm-352 0c-39.8 0-72 32.2-72 72s32.2 72 72 72 72-32.2 72-72-32.2-72-72-72z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg></span></td>]
```

I am able to get all the `table` text with this line

```
cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
```

but substituting **span.text** does not work  I need the `span` value of

```
fxs_c_impact-icon fxs_c_impact-none
```

for impact for each row of text

I am trying extract all the `span` text from a `table`

```
data3 = []
table3 = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'fxs_c_table'})
table_body3 = table3.find('tbody')

rows = table_body3.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.span.text for ele in cols]
    data3.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
```

The `span` item looks like this

```
<span class="fxs_c_impact-icon fxs_c_impact-medium"></span>
```

Error I get

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The script works if I want to extract text from text fields from the table but I cant seem to extract this span text value.

Comment: What is the rerason to extract text from an element that seems to have no text at all? You should also make sure that each cell you iterate contains a corresponding `span`.

Comment: The error implies that some of the TD don't have SPAN. Why not use `row.find_all('span')`?

Comment: So help us to help you and provide an example of the table as well as expected output, please.  As well I am with @barmar be more specific `row.find('span',{'class' : 'fxs_c_impact-icon'}).get('class')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, try to select the elements more specific.

```
.find('span',{'class' : 'fxs_c_impact-icon'}).get('class')[-1]
```

Because the main issue is that there is one `td` that do not have a `span`:

```
<td class="fxs_c_item fxs_c_notify"></td>
```

So `ele.span` will become `None` and you could not call `.text` on it.

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<tr>
<td class="fxs_c_item fxs_c_time"><span>01:00</span></td>
 <td class="fxs_c_item fxs_c_flag"><span class="fxs_flag fxs_us" title="United States"></span></td>
 <td class="fxs_c_item fxs_c_currency"><span>USD</span></td>
 <td class="fxs_c_item fxs_c_name"><span>New Year's Day</span><span> <span></span></span></td>
 <td class="fxs_c_item fxs_c_impact"><span class="fxs_c_impact-icon fxs_c_impact-none"></span></td>
 <td class="fxs_c_item fxs_c_type" colspan="4"><span class="fxs_c_label fxs_c_label_info">All Day</span></td>
 <td class="fxs_c_item fxs_c_notify"></td>
 <td class="fxs_c_item fxs_c_dashboard" data-gtmid="features-calendar-eventdetails-eventoptions-4d3300ad-c168-4a5f-a4ac-a60a338e63c4"><span><svg aria-hidden="true" class="fxs_icon svg-inline--fa fa-ellipsis-h fa-w-16" data-icon="ellipsis-h" data-prefix="fas" focusable="false" role="img" viewbox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M328 256c0 39.8-32.2 72-72 72s-72-32.2-72-72 32.2-72 72-72 72 32.2 72 72zm104-72c-39.8 0-72 32.2-72 72s32.2 72 72 72 72-32.2 72-72-32.2-72-72-72zm-352 0c-39.8 0-72 32.2-72 72s32.2 72 72 72 72-32.2 72-72-32.2-72-72-72z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg></span></td>
</tr>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data = []
    
for e in soup.find_all('tr'):
    data.append(
        {
            'time': e.span.text,
            'title':  e.find('span',{'class' : 'fxs_flag'}).get('title'),
            'currency': e.find('td',{'class' : 'fxs_c_currency'}).text,
            '...': '...',
            'impact': e.find('span',{'class' : 'fxs_c_impact-icon'}).get('class')[-1]
        }
    )

data
```

###### Output

```
[{'time': '01:00','title': 'United States','currency': 'USD', '...':'...','impact': 'fxs_c_impact-none'}]
```

Comment: I am getting an error
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: when get is applied to title

Comment: my fault -  `e.find('span',{'class' : 'fxs_flag'})` but you should also check the availability of the element like `e.find('span',{'class' : 'fxs_flag'}).get('title') if e.find('span',{'class' : 'fxs_flag'}) else None`